# How to document Xamarin.iOS vs iOS

Tags: discussion, documentation

I'd like to add some useful elements to the documentation currently in beta, and I'm specifically interested in iOS.

The iOS SDK is available in Objective-C and Swift, but also in Xamarin, and probably many other languages.

Should I write in the Xamarin.iOS section, or iOS, or both? I want to add the Xamarin code, for the iOS framework, so it's kind of valid for both.

Currently, it looks like there is gonna be an incredible amount of duplicate documentation since it's exactly the same framework (iOS), hence the same calls and rules, just not the same language.

In iOS, people write answers in Objective-C and Swift, do you guys think it would be okay to edit an example and add the Xamarin relevant code, or should I just re-write the complete example in the Xamarin.iOS section, even though it already exists somewhere else?

Either way, it either feels messy or duplicate.